No Destination Tag
i transfered my wrapped ETH in SOL Network from my 1st Wallet to my 2nd Wallet. The Destination Tag or Memo was wrong or deleted idk. So the ETH is in my 2nd Wallet i can see it but cant use it. because the System created automaticly a 3rd Wallet where my Wrapped ETH now is what can i do. Everywhere it says go to support
